# Hibernate - Spring, SessionFactory nullPointerException (when calling getCurrentSession())

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I try to save my `PartageDomain` in my database using hibernate session factory, the problem is that in `Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` a `nullPointerException` is thrown. My dataSource is well configured, and I can already  save/persist other objects with exactly the same way in this project, so I don't khow where the problem comes from.

a snapshot from the console exception :

```
javax.faces.FacesException: /pages/indexx.xhtml @28,72 listener="#{userMB.saveUserRights}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)

.....

javax.el.ELException: /pages/indexx.xhtml @28,72 listener="#{userMB.saveUserRights}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:447)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:911)

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.stage.dao.PartageDaoImpl.add(PartageDaoImpl.java:35)
    at com.stage.beans.UserManagedBean.saveUserRights(UserManagedBean.java:224)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    ... 23 more
```

here is part of code from the partageDomainImpl class :

```
@Repository
public class PartageDaoImpl implements PartageDao, Serializable {
@Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
// sessionFactory getter and setter :)

public void add(PartageDomain partageDomain) {      System.out.println(partageDomain.getPartageId().getUserDomain().getFirstName()); // I get this
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // Save
        try {
            session.persist(partageDomain);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.saveOrUpdate(partageDomain);
        }
    }
```

Note that the exception is not caused by the EL langage, in fact I get the object correctly by printing it before calling the `getsessionFactory` method from which come the exception

in my PartageDomain class I have :

```
@Entity
public class PartageDomain implements Serializable {
// the PartageDomain properties, getters and setters ....
```

In fact I'm showing that to you to mention that I'm using annotation to manage dependencies and injections, concerning my session factory, I declared it in my configuration file as

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="com.stage"/>
```

Comment: Have you set <context:annotation-config/> and/or <context:component-scan/> in your XML ?

Comment: they are all set properly, I use them already to save other objects that I have : <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> <context:component-scan base-package="com.myBasePack" /> <mvc:annotation-driven /> <context:annotation-config/>

Comment: how do you inject PartageDaoImpl to UserManagedBean ?

Comment: for the UserManagedBean I use @Controller, and for the PartageDaoImpl I use the @Service("userService"). I think this is not my problem, because in the same manner I can save other objects that I have using the same annotation logic in injections

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess - 
It is possible that you have a conflict in your context files.

I think that your `@Repository` annotated bean is somehow being created in the servlet application context, while `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />` is declared in the root web app context.

In other words the `@Transactional` works only in the context where `tx:annotation-driven` is declared.

I suppose that it's possible for some the beans to be autoscanned and created twice making them to exist both in the web application and servlet application contexts, if autoscanning is present in both context configurations.

So the solution may be to check that all beans are created once and in the right places - DAOs in the root context, Controllers in the servlet context etc.

*update*
Also please note that this code uses catch em all exception handling antipattern and possibly accesses hibernate session after it has raised an exception which is not supported by Hibernate as I know.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but in fact, I'm sure that beans are created only once,>> I'm using the factoryBeans Design pattern, in addition, when I remove the @Repository, an exception says that I don't have this beans, on the other hand, in the case we have 2 instances of the same bean, an exception indicationg that we have two instances os normally shown in the console lines. Note that I'm using my userManagedBean as ViewScoped,in which I declare the userService as ManagedProperty;is that can cause the problem ? personnally I don't think so,because the exception is relative sessionFactory

Comment: Relating to your response, I want to know more about the places in wich the beans are created, and about the different behaviors of beans created in the application context,in the root context ..., so if you have some good links I ll be graceful,

Comment: You can have the same beans in *different* contexts, and removing @Repository will make them disappear from both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616410/transactional-methods-in-controller-class-are-not-considred-as-transactional/9616556#9616556

Comment: mm I see, thank you @Boris for your clarification, now I still searching a solution to my problem, I have no Idea where it comes from :s, some help would be graceful

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051721/declarative-transactions-transactional-doesnt-work-with-repository-in-sprin

Comment: btw your session code seems to be broken in hibernate afaik it's strongly prohibited to continue using the session after it has  raised an exception

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem, in fact, it's my `partageServiceImpl` that has the `sessionfactory` property managed by spring-hibernate injection system.

In my `userManagedBean`, I was calling directly the the `PartageDaoImpl.add` method to add the `partageDomain` object, the correct thing is to call the `PartageServiceImpl.add` which has the `sessionFactory` property, in this whay the `currentSession` will not be null

I admit that it's a grave error that I made and It costs to me the whole day trying to solving it, so I hope this error will be faslty corrected by the others when seeying the exception that I have.